# function which checks the char length and cuts it down if it is too long

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon,

Any help would be most appreciated. I can get my script to run in the console correctly; presenting the modified text length if it is too long.

However, I cannot seem to replace the innerHTML if it is too long.

My mind is drawing a blank and any attempt I make seems to produce the below error.

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'innerHTML' on string'

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>temp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>test</h1>
        <p id="description">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscin.        </p>
        <p id="another_one">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio.
        </p>
<script>
'use strict';
function ShowMore(el, stop) {
    this.e = document.getElementById(el);
    this.stop = stop;
    this.get_length = function() {
        return this.e.innerText.length;
    };
    this.stop_length = function() {
        if (this.get_length() > this.stop) {
            return this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.stop);
        } else {
            return this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.get_length());
        }
    };
};
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let intro = new ShowMore('description', 300);
    intro.innerHTML = intro.stop_length();
    console.log(intro.stop_length());
    let outro = new ShowMore('another_one', 300);
    console.log(outro.stop_length());
});

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let intro = new ShowMore('description', 300)` doesn't return a DOM Element, it creates an `Object`.

[`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) only works on Element Nodes.

Maybe you want to do `intro.e.innerHTML = intro.stop_length()`, as `this.e` refers to an Element.

```js
function ShowMore(el, stop) {
    this.e = document.getElementById(el);
    this.stop = stop;
    this.get_length = function() {
        return this.e.innerText.length;
    };
    this.stop_length = function() {
        if (this.get_length() > this.stop) {
            return this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.stop);
        } else {
            return this.e.innerText.substr(0, this.get_length());
        }
    };
}

let intro = new ShowMore('test', 50);
intro.e.innerHTML = intro.stop_length();
```

```html
<div id="test">werw ekropwekrop wekopr kweoprop werkopw ekropkweop rkpwoe kropwerkopw ekrwerwerwer wer wer wer werw erwe rwer wer wer wer wer wer wer wer weopwekop rwer w</div>
```

Comment: @dean thank you! It was the 'e' bit I was foolishly missing. You're a rockstar thank you for your swift assistance.

Comment: @dimButTries It happens to the best of us, don't be so hard on yourself. Glad I could help.